# Working of Combiner and Reducer class in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have data for the scores of students of a particular class in the following format

```
StudentId@CourseId@Marks1@Marks2@Marks3@Marks4@Marks5

01001@104@13@18@25@86@23
01001@106@58@30@10@12@59
01001@108@60@81@97@83@26
01001@110@68@95@11@73@63
01001@112@55@22@74@71@22
01002@104@20@72@76@28@99
01002@106@52@17@20@67@91
01002@108@18@46@61@73@14
01002@110@86@59@50@35@65
01002@112@45@76@97@37@17
.......
```

I want to compute the average of the scores obtained by a student in 5 different courses (Given By 5 Different Course IDs) in 5 different exams.

My Map and Reduce Classes for the above are as follows :

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,DoubleWritable>{
    private Text SID=new Text();
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text,DoubleWritable> output,Reporter reporter)throws IOException{
        String data=value.toString();
        String arr[]=data.split("@");
        int i=2;
        double score=0;
        while(i<arr.length){
            score+=Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
            i++;
        }
        //Dividing The Score to give the average score in a particular course
        score=score/5;
        SID.set(arr[0]);
        output.collect(SID,new DoubleWritable(score));
    }
}
```

and

```
  public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text,DoubleWritable,Text,DoubleWritable>{
    public void reduce(Text key,Iterator<DoubleWritable> values,OutputCollector<Text,DoubleWritable> output,Reporter reporter)throws IOException{
        double Total=0.0;
        while(values.hasNext()){
            Total+=values.next().get(); 
        }
        //Dividing By 5 to obtain the average score for a particular student
        output.collect(key,new DoubleWritable((Total/5)));              
    }
}
```

Besides, In The Main Class, apart from defining other configurations, I have set the above `Reduce` class as both the `Reducer` as well as the `Combiner` class.

However the output I obtained was as following

```
 01001  9.879999999999999
 01002  10.568
 01003  8.712
 01004  10.68
 01005  9.335999999999999
 ....
```

This shows that the total score of a student is being divided by 125 and not 25.
However, on removing the statement `score=score/5` from the `Map` class,
I got the correct result. Now from what I could understand (and am not very sure about that),it is because the `Reducer` and `Combiner` classes are the same in this case. Is that so?
How is the `Combiner` class working in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combiner is executed on each node after executing the map.

Yet need to divide by 5 (the number of different courses) only at the very end of the summation. Therefore you only can divide at the end of the reducer and not at the end of the combiner.

Basically you can either:

- Remove the combiner (but keep the reducer)
- Define a reducer that does exactly the same as the reducer but does not divide at the end